# MVC5 How to write checkbox values from user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok so I got my check box going, I have my options and if I select any, I want to write the submitted selected item's value, sounds easy right? well every time I click any option and submit it, the value is displayed on the URL, but I cant seem to write it out...

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@using vgsimulator.Models
@model List<vgsimulator.Models.Album>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Album ka = new Album();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(it => it[i].Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(it => it[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => it[i].Checked)
    }
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    <p>@Viewbag.Values</p> //here we print values checked
}
```

Model(Album.cs):

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Controller(HomeController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = new List<Album>
    {
        new Album { Id = 1, Name = "Aquafina", Checked = false },
        new Album { Id = 2, Name = "Mulshi Springs", Checked = false },
        new Album { Id = 3, Name = "Alfa Blue", Checked = false },
        .....
    };
    return View(list);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Album> list)
{
    //ViewBag.Values = x?;
    return this.View(list);
}
```

Comment: Your form is using GET, so your data actually gets submitted to the first Index() action

Comment: @Kurorion hmm I don't get it, what's a possible solution? and thanks

Comment: Remove the `FormMethod.Get` from your form and it'll submit via POST, which will call your `public ActionResult Index(List<Album> list)` instead of `public ActionResult Index()`

Comment: @Kurorion ok then what? how do I print the values that I checked?

Comment: In `public ActionResult Index(List<Album> list)` you have your list of submitted albums.  From there you can figure out which ones are checked, as for how you want to display them in your view that's up to you.

Comment: @Kurorion hmmm, howabout we  enter a private chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112447/discussion-between-fluffywuffy-and-kurorion).

Comment: First you need to change it to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` or just `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and then you could use `var selected = list.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Name); ViewBag.Values = String.Join(", ", list); return View(list);` But what is the point of this - your UI makes no sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke help, I'm still running into issues, want to join a private room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the selected values in the view when you return in in the post method, first add a hidden input for the `Name` property so it posts back

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m[i].Name)
```

and then modify the POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Album> list)
{
    var selected = list.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Name);
    ViewBag.Values = String.Join(", ", selected );
    return View(list);
}
```

which will display a comma separated list of all the selected `Album` in the `<p>` element.

Of course, this UI makes no sense, but from the comments its was just a test to be able to get the selected items, before writing the code to save them. Assuming your wanted to store the selected `Album` collection for users of your app, you might have a table (say) `UserAlbums` which would contain fields for the `UserId` and the `AlbumId`, then to save the selected items, you would use something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Album> list)
{
    var userId = ....; // get the ID of the current user
    IEnumerable<int> selected = list.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Id);
    foreach(int id in selected)
    {
        db.Add(new UserAlbum() { UserId = userId, AlbumId = id });
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(...); // redirect to another view
}
```